# How to skip entire file when iterating through folder?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a file path with many files in it.

Some of the files dont have the data I want in them, how do I skip over these files and move on to the next set of files?

```
path ='/path/' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.json")
for file_ in allFiles:
    #print(file_)
    with open(file_) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        df = json_normalize(data['col_to_be_flattened']) 
        REST OF THE OPERATIONS
```

once the data is in the dataframe at the point `df`, the `REST OF THE OPERATIONS` relies on a column called 'Rows.Row', if this column does not exist in `df` I want to skip it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if 'Rows.Row' is in the title of the columns before continue.

```
path ='/path/' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.json")
for file_ in allFiles:
    #print(file_)
    with open(file_) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        df = json_normalize(data['col_to_be_flattened'])
        if 'Rows.Row' in df.columns.tolist():
            REST OF THE OPERATIONS
```

Comment: thank you so much that did it! I didnt realize if added 'if' the file it self would skip over.